# What is the best way to implement parallel state machine in NuSMV version 2.6?

Tags: state-machine, nusmv

I am trying to convert a state machine (given in `scxml`) to `NuSMV` version 2.6, and I came across this in the user manual:
[image]

What is the best way to go around it? What is the best way to represent a parallel state machine in NuSMV without processes?
There is the flatten method, but it is very complicated when there are more than 3 states. So I seek a better way.

Thank you!